# Minikube dashboard and any other pods won't schedule

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

After following the [hello-minikube guide](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateless-application/hello-minikube/) and installing minikube 0.26.1 the dashboard pod is not starting and also the [hello-minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/minikube/#quickstart) pod is not getting started.

A `kubectl describe pod xxx` shows that the pod could not get scheduled.

```
Events:
 Type     Reason            Age                  From              Message
 ----     ------            ----                 ----               -------
 Warning  FailedScheduling  3m (x3368 over 16h)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taints that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This has to do with [taints and tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2017/03/advanced-scheduling-in-kubernetes) in k8s versions starting from 1.6.
By default the master node has a `NoSchedule` taint.

```
# kubectl describe node minikube
Name:               minikube
Roles:              master
[...]
Taints:             node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule
```

You can add tolerations to the pods as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48496629/1326662) - but in my case I do not want to edit any pod specs as I want to test my deployments locally 1:1 as in a live k8s environment.

The other option is to delete the taint on the master node. See the documentation [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) and [there](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/independent/create-cluster-kubeadm/).

```
kubectl taint nodes --all node-role.kubernetes.io/master-
```

In the specific case of a local minikube setup with only one node and testing deployments locally without adding tolerations this works as well:

```
kubectl taint nodes minikube node-role.kubernetes.io/master:NoSchedule-
```

This should be part of the minikube getting started guide imho.

Comment: This was very useful I think you should mark it as the answer even if you did answer your own question!