# How to deploy specific pod to all nodes including master, but only for specific pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a security pod that needs to run everywhere including master.  I do not want, however, master to run any other (non kubernetes) pods. 
I know I can taint master node, and I know I can setup affinity for a pod.  Yet (unless I am misunderstanding something) that isn't quite what I want.

What I want is to setup affinity in a way that  this security pod runs on every single node including master as a part of same daemon set.   It is important that I only have a single definition due to how this security pod gets deployed.

Can this be done?

I am running Kubernetes 1.8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scheduler is not scheduling Pod for DaemonSet in Master node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495263/scheduler-is-not-scheduling-pod-for-daemonset-in-master-node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is more or less duplicate to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48495263/scheduler-is-not-scheduling-pod-for-daemonset-in-master-node/48496629#48496629).

What you need is a combination of two features:

- [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset) will allow you to schedule Pod to run on every node
- [Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/) in the DaemonSet Pods will allow this workload to run even on the node which has the master taint.

That way your security pods will run everywhere even on the master with the taint because they can tolerate it. I think there is an example directly on the [DaemonSet website](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/#create-a-daemonset).

But other pods without this toleration will not be scheduled on master because they do not tolerate the taint.

Comment: Darn it, and I was searching for a question as I assumed someone already asked it.
Thank you! That's what I needed!